# An Injection from $[\mathbb N\to\mathbb N]$ to $[\mathbb N\to[\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}]]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'd really like some help/clues with finding an injection from
 $[\mathbb N\to\mathbb N]$ to $[\mathbb N\to[\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}]]$.
**Without using Cardinal arithmetic**
Thank you so much.

Comment: Hint: find an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}\}$

Comment: @noctusraid Thanks!! solved it =)

Comment: Nice to hear! You're welcome!